# Отсчёт времени после старта программы JAVA

Tags: java, android

Мучаюсь уже часов 5, не могу додуматься как это сделать:

В общем, есть код, запрашивающий значения (координаты) маркера. Так вот, в самом начале - переменные для него равны нулю, после того, как пришёл ответ от сервера с координатами - его нужно поместить на карту. Нужно сделать задержку примерно в 3-4 секунды при этом не тормозя остальной код приложения. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Почитайте про многопоточность. Создавайте отдельный `Thread` и выполняйте код в нем после задержки через `sleep`.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^"

Answer (score 6):

Создавать потоки на такие вещи не рекомендую.

Если промежуток небольшой, то лучше использовать `ScheduledExecutorService`.

Для долгих пауз лучше использовать `BroadcastReciever` и `AlarmManager`.

Пример с `ScheduledExecutorService`:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
  private ScheduledExecutorService mScheduleTaskExecutor;

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mScheduleTaskExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    // будет вызвано через 3 секунды
    mScheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {

      public void run() {       
        // если что-то в гуи делать надо
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
             // делаем что-то в гуи
          }
        });
      }
    }, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  } 
}
```