# Таймер JAVA android

Tags: java, android

Вопрос такой: Нужно сделать так, чтобы int раз в 5 секунд меняла своё значение. (В начале 0, через 5 секунд - 1, 1 на одну секунду, потом опять 0 и так до бесконечности) Так же, чтобы всё это не останавливало остальную работу программы.

Comment: имеется ли у вас код, который не работает или вызывает проблему? пожалуйста, приложите к вопросу, нажав на кнопку `править`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Отсчёт времени после старта программы JAVA](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/744813/%d0%9e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%87%d1%91%d1%82-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%8b-java)