# Работа с таймером. Выполнить код через время

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Приветствую. Работаю в Android Studio.

Нужно сделать так, чтобы цвет activity стал красным и сразу же через 500 миллисекунд (допустим, можно и через секунду) цвет стал таким, как раньше - белым или какой-там стандартный цвет.

```
public class AllotmentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.allotment_activity);

    }

    public void no(View view){
        mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rel);
        mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
//        SystemClock.sleep(500);
//        mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
```

Здесь, в этом коде, меняется только цвет activity на красный. Но нужно еще чтобы через некоторое время цвет снова поменялся на тот, что был изначально.

Пробовал с помощью SystemClock.sleep(500);, но тогда получается не то, что нужно...

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Отсчёт времени после старта программы JAVA](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/744813/%d0%9e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%87%d1%91%d1%82-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%8b-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте через Handler:

```
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {


             // через  5 сек выполниться действие описанное тут 
                mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);


        }
    }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void no(View view){
    mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rel);
    int color = Color.TRANSPARENT;
    Drawable background = mRelativeLayout.getBackground();
    if (background instanceof ColorDrawable)
        color = ((ColorDrawable) background).getColor();
    mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    mRelativeLayout.postDelayed(() -> mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(color), 500);
}
```